# addTarget to custom button Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a problem with `addTarget` to my custom button in Swift 4. I tried everything, but still have problem to define selector, because result is always error.

Any idea?

```
let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
myButton.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400)
myButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 18.0
myButton.setTitle("Tap Me", for: UIControlState.normal)
myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
myButton.actions(forTarget: self, forControlEvent: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
myButton.isHighlighted = true
self.view.addSubview(myButton)
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding your code as an unreadable comment.

Comment: 1. The code you posted makes no attempt to call `addTarget` so what are you referring to? 2. Point out the exact line causing your error. 3. Include the complete and exact error message in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnClickAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Button action method

```
@objc func btnClickAction(_ sender:UIButton) {
        print("My custom button action")
    }
```

Comment: What is clicking? Which part of an iPhone clicks when you press a button? Don’t use a word that has no meaning on an iPhone. Also, what does that function do? Why not call the function for what it does?